# Showing Number of Cart Items instead of Cart total price in navbar Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopping-cart

In my rails app I have this code in my `_navbar.html.erb`

```
            <% if @cart.total_price > 0 %>
                <%= link_to @cart do %> 
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"> &euro; </i>
                <%=  @cart.total_price %>
                <% end %>

                <% else %>
                    <a href="#" class="menu-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> &euro; 0.00</a>
                <% end %>
```

It displays the `@cart.total_price` but I want it to display the total items in the Cart instead.

I'm not sure how to do that

Most of this code is from a Udemy tutorial, but it's getting little bit to much for my experience so I feel kind a lost trying to modify this to my needs.

I've been trying to add the `@product_item`to the above code but with out a luck, can anyone take a look at this and guide me through this.

I have this code in the `application_controller.rb`

```
before_action :set_cart    

def set_cart
   @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
   @cart = Cart.create
   session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
end
```

In the `carts_controller.rb` I have this:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :destroy]
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart

def new
    @cart = Cart.new
end

def show
     @images  = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"]
 @random_no = rand(5)
 @random_image = @images[@random_no]

end


def destroy
    @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your Cart is Empty'
end


private

def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
end

def cart_params
    params[:cart]
end

def invalid_cart
    logger_error = 'You are trying to access invalid cart'
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Invalid Cart'
end
end
```

In the `controllers/concerns` I've this file `current_cart.rb`

```
module CurrentCart

private

def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
end
end
```

Then I have the `product_items_controller.rb` and there is this code:

```
class ProductItemsController < ApplicationController

include CurrentCart

before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
before_action :set_product_item, only: [:show, :destroy]

def create

    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @product_item = @cart.add_product(@product.id)
    if @product_item.save
        redirect_to root_url, notice:'Product added to Cart'
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private

def set_product_items
    @product_item = ProductItem.find(params[:id])
end

def product_item_params
    params.require(:product_item).permit(:product_id)
end

end
```

And the relevant models are `cart.rb` and `product_item.rb`

in the `cart.rb`I have this code:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :product_items, dependent: :destroy

def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = product_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
        current_item.quantity += 1
    else
        current_item = product_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
end

def total_price
    product_items.to_a.sum{|item| item.total_price}
end

end
```

And in the `product_item.rb` there is this code:

```
class ProductItem < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :product
 belongs_to :cart
 belongs_to :order


 def total_price
    product.price * quantity
 end

end
```

Comment: shouldn't it just be summing up all the `quantity` of all the `product_items` that are associated with the `cart`?

Comment: Yes exactly, but I'm not sure how to write that in to the navbar code... at the moment this is somehow to complex for my lack of ruby experience

Comment: `<%= @cart.products.count %>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want total items in the cart, just take the sum of the `quantity` column over `product_items` in your `Cart` model, like this:

```
def total_quantity
  product_items.sum(:quantity)
end
```

Then you can just call `@cart.total_quantity` from the view (or anywhere else).

Note that by calling `sum` on `product_items`, which is a relation (and not an array), this directly calculates the sum using SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(`product_items`.`quantity`) FROM product_items
  WHERE `product_items`.`cart_id` = 123
```

where `123` is the id of the cart.

This is more efficient than calling `sum` on an *array* of product items (i.e. `product_items.to_a.sum(&:quantity)`), which would load each product item, then sum the quantities. But either should work, and depending on what you're doing the latter `sum` may suit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the `@cart` code in the `_navbar.html.erb` to look like this, it should work just like the previous chunk but shows the `product_items.count`instead of the `total_price`

```
<% if @cart.product_items.count > 0 %>
  <%= link_to @cart do %> 
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  <%= @cart.product_items.count %>
  <% end %>

  <% else %>
     <a href="#" class="menu-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> 0 </a>
<% end %>
```